# Do we need the definite article before designation plus organization?

Tags: grammar, definite-articles

If I write `Mr. ABC, President of the XYZ Corporation, . . .` do I need to use `the` before `President`? I know it is must when we are mentioning organizations, but what about designation (more specifically, designation with organization, if it matters at all)?

Comment: Why is it a "must when we are mentioning organizations"? What is the source of that rule?

Comment: @Kris So you're telling me you'd write a sentence like `President of United States is expected tonight`? <cringes>

Comment: Not necessarily.

Comment: @Kris Yes or no? And by which rule?

Comment: That was my Question :)

Comment: @Kris All I was trying to do was show that you were being unhelpful in your original answer. Now, can I *request* you to express your opinion on the use of the definite article before the designation in my original example? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends how, in a sentence, or in a designation it is written. I could for example write:

'Francois Hollande, President of France, is hosting a banquet in Versailles.' The words 'President of France' are simply being used as a designation, and form a subordinate adjectival clause to the name.

But if I refer to him by title only I would have to say:

The President of France, and all the other leaders of the G8, are dining at the Palais de Versailles tonight.

Comment: Of course if I was speaking in French I would have to say 'Francois Hollande, le president de la France', since the article is never omitted, even in 'Monsieur le President'.